# Firebird UTF-8 German phonebook sorting

Tags: sorting, utf-8, firebird, firebird2.5

Server: Windows 2008 R2 x64 with Firebird 2.5 x64
I need a sorting methode like the German phonebook at a Query e.g.

SELECT Name, Forename
    FROM Address
    ORDER BY Name, Forename;

I want as result:

Name, Forename

1. Assemann, Simon
2. Aßmann, Erika
3. Assmann, Frank
4. Astmann, Manfred
5. Hacker, Simon
6. Hackmann, Gustav
7. Häcker, Emil
8. Haecker, Manfred
9. Häcker, Xaver
10. Hafermann, Ulrich

In the German phonebook sorting, the German special characters are handled at following way:

- Ä/ä = Ae/ae
- Ö/ö = Oe/oe
- Ü/ü = Ue/ue
- ß = ss

Other special characters like the French ones (á, à…) is handled like the normal characters (a,a…).

I’m trying du Upgrade the ICS*.dll from Version 3.0 to 5.0 or 5.6 but it doesn’t work.

Comment: What character set and collation are you currently using for this column?

Comment: Seems like utf-8 as seen in the tags.

Comment: @Booser Yes, but that doesn't specify the collation used. By default the collations available for UTF-8 under Firebird are UCS_BASIC, UNICODE, UNICODE_CI and UNICODE_CI_AI none of which provide German specific sorting. There is also an option to create custom/locale specific collations.

Comment: The entire Database uses Charset UTF-8 actually I have tried the UNICODE Collation but it doesn't work properly.

Comment: That is because the UNICODE collation doesn't provide the sort order you want. I just tried to define a collation using ICU 5.6 on Firebird 2.5.5, but I ran into all sorts of fun problems, I eventually got it to work, but I can't seem to define a collation that uses the German phonebook sort.

Comment: I have posted question to the Firebird development mailinglist to ask what I missed or did wrong, I will post the conclusions when I have received answers and have been able to test them.