# Upgrading ICU*.dll on a Firebird 2.5.2

Tags: dll, firebird, firebird2.5

I’m trying to Upgrade the ICU*.dll from Version 3.0 to Version 5.0/5.6

I have performed following steps:

1. Stop the Firebird
2. Remove the ICU*30.dll from the /bin/ folder
3. Insert the ICU*50.dll/ICU*56.dll
4. Edit the fbintl.conf in /intl/ folder

   `<intl_module builtin>
       icu_versions    5.6 default
   </intl_module>`
5. Start the Firebird server.

The Server does not start after these steps, I tried different Versions of the fbintl.conf but it does not work.

The Server only starts when the ICU*30.dll is in the /bin/ folder, but in this case the Server does not load the ICU*50.fll/ICU*56.dll.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35581763/firebird-utf-8-german-phonebook-sorting

Comment: Do you have the right bitness (so 64 bit for a 64 bit Firebird install). When I looked at your previous question I could load the dll and use functionality not in the default icu30, but I believe the icu30 files still need to be there. However there is an additional problem with the ICU support, because, apparently, ICU changed their version numbering scheme from icu30 meaning 3.0 to icu56 meaning version 56.x instead of 5.6; it might be that that causes problems. I'm still looking into this, but the Firebird core developers aren't really forthcoming with help/information on this.